# addressing winmail.dat in Outlook from receiver standpoint

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, winmail.dat

I have a customer who is getting an email sent to them everyday in Outlook RTF format.
It is a bulk email that many people in his organization gets every day.

1. Everyone (senders/receiver) is using Outlook.
2. The recipient email system is OpenSRS (not Google or O365).
3. Everyone else can read the email but **he gets it as winmail.dat** (this is the issue)
4. He can see it in webmail

I know that the best solution is for the sender to use HTML instead of RTF when they are sending, but I have 2 questions:

1. Why can everyone read the email except for him?
2. Is there any way to address it from his end, vs trying to persuade the sender (a 3rd party) to use a different format?

EDIT:
I realize the best solution is to have the sender change to HTML format, but I have no say in that. Everyone is using Outlook so RTF should work.
I need to fix it from the receiver end if possible.
As a workaround, I installed an app called "winmail.dat explorer" which allows the end user to open and read the winmail.dat file.

Comment: The error is perhaps caused by OpenSRS. Can't you convince that one user to abandon it?

Comment: There are about 5 other people on the same OpenSRS domain that receive and can open the email. It is also viewable in OpenSRS email.
I don't think it's OpenSRS for those reasons.
I think there is some configuration on his computer somewhere that is causing this issue.

Comment: Is there anything unique for that user, such as security software or other installed products/extension?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how outlook RTF works.

When you send an email in RTF format, the attachment is embedded inline and the file is attached as winmail.dat.

The winmail.dat file is a container that holds all the attachments.

In the body of the email, where the attachment is placed, there is some extra information regarding what the attachment is and how to get it from the winmail.dat.

Microsoft Outlook is the only client that knows how to deal with RTF and winmail.dat files (and Microsoft 365 webmail can too, but technically is not a client), and will succesfully decode the email.

Given that everyone but one person uses Outlook, everyone but that person is able to see the attachments.

**How to solve the issue?**

There are only two options.

1. Everyone sends email as HTML or Text Only, and not use the outlook only RTF format.
2. Everyone uses Outlook.

Option 1 is the preferred solution here because you found a problem that seems to be inside your organisation, but it is not. Outside of your organisation, the same problem exists too. Unless the recipient is also using Outlook, they too will get a winmail.dat.

This is mostly a problem for Mac users, given that they often use Mac's Mail client, and not Microsoft Outlook for Mac.

There is no way for someone on the winmail.dat side to decrypt the attachment unless they use Microsoft Outlook or webmail in case of Microsoft 365.

Comment: The email is being sent from Outlook and all recipients (about 6) use Outlook. Only one of the recipients see the email as winmail.dat. He was using Outlook 2013 so I uninstalled in and installed Office 2019 but get the same problem. 
I've talked to the sender about sending using HTML but they are outside of the organization and I don't have a good feeling that they care enough to change it. They are copying and pasting out of another program into Outlook and sending the email.

Comment: SO, for some reason, that Outlook on that one computer cannot parse the winmail.dat file.

Comment: It may be that the OpenSRS is causing the body of the email to be changed and the information to decode the winmail.dat is lost.

Comment: All the recipients are on OpenSRS. I do believe this is an issue on that on computer but I don't know why.

Comment: If so, maybe you can compare the specific computer with other computers to check if there're any differences.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with LPChip, this issue is related to RTF. And we can set "Compose in this message format" as HTML or Plain Text to avoid it. For more information, please refer to: [How email message formats affect Internet email messages in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-email-message-formats-affect-internet-email-messages-in-outlook-3b2c0536-c1c0-1d68-19f0-8cae13c26722).

[image]

On the other hand, I found there's a registry to [prohibit Outlook from sending the Winmail.dat file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/winmail-dat-sent-as-an-email-attachment-in-outlook-2007-and-2010-b72c81ac-db5e-b142-d43d-448efbc23cce). Maybe it will work.
For the path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Preferences
```

please note: The xx.0 placeholder represents your version of Office (16.0 = Office 2016, Office 365 and Office 2019, 15.0 = Office 2013)

(Note: Serious problems can occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before making changes, [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) to restore it in case something goes wrong.)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.